# Use SharePoint:MultipleLookupField control in visual web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

In visual studio, I had a drop down list whose data source was connected to a LINQ query. Because there are many records, the client ask for a searchable control. I have replaced the drop down list with MultipleLookupField in the ascx page in visual studio. How can I bind this control to a data source? Is it possible to show checkbox beside each records?

Comment: Instead of using MultipleLookupField, would you prefer to use AutoComplete on a textbox control? You can use CAML query to filter the data. Complete doc is at http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/value-added/SPAutocomplete.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you create visual web part in SharePoint 2010, SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint 2016?

Per my test in my SharePoint 2013 environment, then I cannot find the SharePoint:MultipleLookupField control which can be added when creating visual web part.

You could add the control and bind the data source using C# code in code behind.
There is a similar post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2e26cea-4b36-471d-a035-f51f693e1ac7/sharepoint-multiplelookupfield-control?forum=sharepointdevelopment